# How to cancel creation of android home screen widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget for my app. On widget Creation when android triggers `onEnabled` I'm checking if a user meets a certain requirement then the user can go ahead and create a widget. But I need to stop widget creation if they don't meet a certain requirement. I can't figure out how to cancel widget creation dynamically. Here's what I was trying which didn't work.

```
RemoteViews views;

void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int appWidgetId) {


    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.lock_widget);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.lock_widget, getPendingSelfIntent(context, LOCK));
    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    // Query User pro status when creating widget
    Log.d("Widget", "OnEnabled Fired");
    views.removeAllViews(views.getLayoutId());
    //views.
}
```

> `views.removeAllViews(views.getLayoutId());` doesn't seem to work.

Is there even a way to this. The workaround that I'm using is checking certain requirement check in `onUpdate`.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that from the `AppWidgetProvider`. You can cancel from a configuration `Activity`, however, if that's an acceptable workaround for you - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#Configuring. Simply call `setResult()` with `RESULT_CANCELED`, instead of `RESULT_OK`. Do note that the `onUpdate()` method will not be called if you use a configuration `Activity`. You'd need to set up the Widget's initial state yourself from that `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks ... AppWidgetConfigureActivity is what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in your case, enable widget component, if user have all "certain requirement".

So i assume a following case. User uses your app, and in some cases (you enable widget component, if user lose his "certain requirement" just disable widget component, so there is no widget in widget picker). You can easily achieve this through PackageManager.

**Updated:** When user have a pro status, just enable widget, if not - just disable

```
public static void setComponentState(Context context, boolean enabled) {
    int flag = (enabled ?
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED :
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED);

    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, YourAppWidgetProvider.class); // or make component via package name and class name (check Component constructors)

    PackageManager pm = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(component, flag, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```